# Insert statement in cx_Oracle produces no records in global temporary table

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've created a global temporary table in sql developer from Python, using the cx_Oracle package.  After creation, the table shows up in my SQL developer application, however INSERT statements produce no records.

I've created a cursor with a working connection(as evidenced by the fact that the tables are successfully created).  In addition, I use the standard syntax for the insert.

I've tried a variety of INSERT statements but none work

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES(example)")
con.commit()
```

I would expect to see the data I've inserted show up.  However when I select * from the table, there is no record inserted.  I am able to successfully insert directly from the SQL developer application, so I'm not sure what might be causing the discrepancy.

Comment: Could it be that temporary tables are only available to the connection/cursor with which they are created?

Comment: How exactly did you create the temporary table?  There are two options, `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` or `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`.  In the first case, data is only available to the transaction that inserted it.  So the commit you run after the `INSERT` would clear out the data from the temporary table.

Comment: Why did you create a GLOBAL TEMPORARY table? What behaviour are you expecting which is (a) different from a normal table? and (b) different from what you're describing here? Maybe you should read [the documentation about GTTs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1138)?

Comment: @APC, I generally use GTTs in SQL developer to store temporary results that I can than use in future selects, joins, etc.  In addition, I do not have permissions to create normal tables in the database I'm working with.  I've tried using ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS, which is what I generally used when creating GTTS in the actual application, but that doesn't help (I still can't write to the GTT from cx_Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Rows added to a global temporary table are only available to the session that created them. Another session, like your SQL Developer session, cannot see them. You have the option of creating the GTT so that rows are deleted at the end of a transaction, or until the session is closed.

See https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused on the definitions of transactions and sessions.  But, if my SQL Developer session cannot see the session created by the cursor in cx_Oracle, how am I able to write to the GTT from within the SQL Developer application?

Comment: That's the whole point of GTTs. Your session cannot see what some other session has put in the table, and vice versa. And once you commit or disconnect, the rows are deleted. I bet if you did a select from your cx_Oracle session, you would see rows there.